# oozie: Could not perform authorization operation, Failed on local exception

Tags: hadoop, oozie

I was trying to run the oozie example from https://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.1.3-incubating/DG_Examples.html
Then I copied the job.properties from examples/apps/aggregator to my home dictionary in local filesystem, and edited it like below:

```
nameNode=hdfs://localhost:9000 
jobTracker=localhost:8032
queueName=default 
examplesRoot=examples
oozie.coord.application.path=${nameNode}/user/${user.name}/${examplesRoot}/apps/aggregator
start=2010-01-01T01:00Z end=2010-01-01T03:00Z
```

I am sure the port is right. Cause `hadoop fs -ls hdfs://localhost:9000` returned the files in hdfs. 
Then I typed this in terminal:

`oozie job -oozie http://127.0.0.1:11000/oozie -config ~/job.properties -run`

, but it returned:

`Error: E0501 : E0501: Could not perform authorization operation, Failed on local exception: com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: Message missing required fields: callId, status; Host Details : local host is: "Master/x.x.x.x"; destination host is: "localhost":9000`

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: did you include `user.name` into properties?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Try to add user.name=hadoop (my user name) to properties file,but problem still remain.

Comment: "protocolbufferexception" is related to google's protocol buffer library, probably its installed version is incompatible with oozie version, try to check the compatibility

Comment: I guess so. I will try cloudera. Thank you again.